# Working inside VPN using an unrooted Android device (or Genymotion)

Tags: vpn, reverse-tether, genymotion

I am trying to use an **unrooted** Android device (or alternatively, a Genymotion emulator) to run an application that needs to be connected to a VPN. On my PC, I only need to connect via Cisco's AnyConnect, and to use a RSA token generator.
However, I'm finding it quite hard to have VPN access in my device. Here are all the approaches that I've followed.

- Installing Cisco AnyConnect for Android didn't work for me, since this can't be done without a token. I can use the generator from my PC, but I don't have a similar software in the device.
- StackOverflow's questions about the "Genymotion approach" don't have any answers, unfortunately. For example, [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732001/connect-to-vpn-in-genymotion-android?rq=1) and [this newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778257/vpn-connection-using-genymotion-emulator).
- Reverse tethering also didn't work. This seems to require a rooted device.
- The last approach I tried was using a laptop as a hotspot, and then connecting to this newly created WiFi network. However, although the network was created, and the Internet connection was succesfully shared, I wasn't able to connect to AnyConnect from the laptop after setting up this network.

Any additional ideas on how to share this VPN access to the device will be highly appreciated. On a final note, the VPN I'm trying to connect to is a customer network, so unfortunately I'm not expecting too much help on they side.
Regards

Comment: what os version ? (API)?